# How to fetch PCF credentials configured in Jenkins variable?

Tags: jenkins, cloud-foundry

Jenkins is configured to deploy PCF application. PCF login credentials is configured in Jenkins as variables. Is there any way to fetch the PCF login credential details from Jenkins variables?

```
echo "Pushing PCF App"
cf login -a https://api.pcf.org.com -u $cduser -p $cdpass -o ORG -s ORG_Dev
cf push pcf-app-04v2\_$BUILD_NUMBER -b java_buildpack -n pcf-app-04v2\_$BUILD_NUMBER -f manifest-prod.yml -p build/libs/*.jar
cf map-route pcf-app-04v2\_$BUILD_NUMBER apps-pr03.cf.org.com --hostname pcf-app
cf delete -f pcf-app
cf rename pcf-app-04v2\_$BUILD_NUMBER pcf-app
cf delete-orphaned-routes -f
```

Comment: It looks like a shell script, so maybe try `echo "user: $cduser"` and `echo "pass: $cdpass"`, where those are the variables defined by Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks for your response @DanielMikusa. When printing the variable value, i see asterisk (*) getting printed instead of user id or password in Jenkins Console Output.

Comment: OK, figured it might be worth a short, but it seems like you need help from someone more knowledgeable with Jenkins than me. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than accessing Jenkins credentials outside to manually run your app, you may probably define a simple pipeline in Jenkins and can define a custom script into it to perform these tasks. In script you can access it through credentials() function and use the environment variable in your commands.

E.g.

```
environment {

CF_USER = credentials('YOUR JENKINS CREDENTIAL KEY')
CF_PWD = credentials('CF_PWD')

}

def deploy() {

script {
sh '''#!/bin/bash
    set -x     
    cf login -a https://api.pcf.org.com -u ${CF_USER} -p ${CF_PWD} -o ORG -s ORG_Dev
    pwd
   '''         
}
```